# How to program combinatorics problems about randomly moving cards from $A$ to $B$ to $C$ to $A$?

Tags: programming, combinatorics

I have a lot of problems with the following scenario, for example,

> Given 3 boxes $A$, $B$ and $C$.
>
> - The box $A$ contains 2 identical cards $x$, 4 identical cards $y$ and 1 card $z$.
> - The box $B$ contains 2 identical cards $x$, 3 identical cards $y$ and 1 card $z$.
> - The box $C$ contains 4 identical cards $x$, 4 identical cards $y$ and no card $z$.
>
> The following actions are performed in the following order
>
> - Randomly move 2 cards from $A$ to $B$.
> - Randomly move 2 cards from $B$ to $C$.
> - Randomly move 3 cards from $C$ to $A$.
>
> Find the probability for the events in which the boxes $A$ and $B$ each still has one card $z$ after performing the three actions above. The cards $z$ are also identical. More precisely, the cards $z$ may move or may not move.

Solving a lot of problems of this kind with bare hands is really error prone.

## Attempt

I have no idea how to program this. Does it need graph representations?

There are only two possible disjoint cases:

- Case 1: The $z$ cards never move.
- Case 2: A single  $z$ card moves from $A$ to $B$ to $C$ and returns to $A$.

Without loss of generality, the $x$ and $y$ cards can actually be considered as $\star$ cards for example.

The initial states for these boxes are

- $A=\{6\star, 1m\}$
- $B=\{5\star, 1m\}$
- $C=\{8\star, 0m\}$

Now calculate the probability for each case.

- Case 1:

  - When moving 2 $\star$ cards from $A=\{6\star,1m\}$, the  probability is $\frac{{6 \choose 2}}{{7\choose 2}}=\frac{5}{7}$. The current state of the involved boxes are $A=\{4\star,1m\}$ and $B=\{7\star,1m\}$.
  - When moving 2 $\star$ cards from $B=\{7\star,1m\}$, the  probability is $\frac{{7 \choose 2}}{{8\choose 2}}=\frac{3}{4}$. The current state of the involved boxes are $B=\{5\star,1m\}$ and  $C=\{10\star,0m\}$.
  - When moving 3 $\star$ cards from $C=\{10\star,0m\}$, the  probability is $\frac{{10 \choose 3}}{{10\choose 3}}=1$. The current state of the involved boxes are $C=\{7\star,0m\}$ and  $A=\{7\star,1m\}$.

  The probability for the first case is $\frac{5}{7}\times \frac{3}{4}=\frac{15}{28}$.
- Case 2:

  - When moving 1 $\star$ card and 1 $z$ card from $A=\{6\star,1m\}$, the  probability is $\frac{{6 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}}{{7\choose 2}}=\frac{2}{7}$. The current state of the involved boxes are $A=\{5\star,0m\}$ and $B=\{6\star,2m\}$.
  - When moving 1 $\star$ card and 1 $z$ card from $B=\{6\star,2m\}$, the  probability is $\frac{{6 \choose 1}{2\choose 1}}{{8\choose 2}}=\frac{3}{7}$. The current state of the involved boxes are $B=\{5\star,1m\}$ and  $C=\{9\star,1m\}$.
  - When moving 1 $\star$ card and 1 $z$ card from $C=\{9\star,1m\}$, the  probability is $\frac{{9 \choose 2}{1\choose 1}}{{10\choose 3}}=\frac{3}{10}$. The current state of the involved boxes are $C=\{7\star,0m\}$ and  $A=\{7\star,1m\}$.

  The probability for the second case is $\frac{2}{7}\times \frac{3}{7} \times \frac{3}{10}=\frac{9}{245}$.

The total probability is $\frac{15}{28}+\frac{9}{245}=\frac{561}{980}$.

Comment: How about a procedure & solution for one of those examples?

Comment: I guess what I mean is that it would be easier to give code suggestions if you gave a solution worked out by hand (i.e. steps to get the total probability and the answer).

Comment: These are more complex urn problems. You may want to look at the documentation for the different distributions available [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/UrnModelDistributions.html). You may need `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution` in this case, however it would make a lot more sense to simulate it.

Comment: @flinty: Thank you for the useful hint or direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a *very* quick-n-dirty. The correct route is to investigate the appropriate multi-urn distributions, which when/if time permits I will do so and update.

A move/result function:

```
domoves[boxes_, from_, to_, count_] := 
  Module[{moves = 
     Join @@ Permutations /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[count, {Length@boxes[[1]]}, Range[0, count]],
     pmf},
   Table[pmf = 
     PDF[MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[count, boxes[[from]]],
       mv];
    If[pmf == 0, Nothing[],
     ReplacePart[
      boxes, {from -> boxes[[from]] - mv, 
       to -> boxes[[to]] + mv, -1 -> boxes[[-1]]*pmf}]], {mv, 
     moves}]];
```

Starting boxes specification:

```
boxes={{2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 0},1};
```

Do the three rounds of moves:

```
round1 = domoves[boxes, 1, 2, 2];
round2 = Flatten[domoves[#, 2, 3, 2] & /@ round1, 1];
round3 = Flatten[domoves[#, 3, 1, 3] & /@ round2, 1];
```

Select results with desired characteristics from final round, total probabilities:

```
Select[round3, #[[1, -1]] == 1 && #[[2, -1]] == 1 &][[All, -1]] // Tr
```

> 561/980

Since the last round contains all possible results, you can reuse it with differing selects to query other result probabilities.

You can polish this framework into a generalized function to take starting state, sequence of moves, and characteristics to get desired probability.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this numerically by simulation as follows:

```
SeedRandom[1];

draw[list_, n_] := TakeDrop[RandomSample[list], n];
simulate[] := Module[{
   a = {x, x, y, y, y, y, z},
   b = {x, x, y, y, y, z},
   c = {x, x, x, x, y, y, y, y}, t},
  {t, a} = draw[a, 2]; b = Join[b, t];
  {t, b} = draw[b, 2]; c = Join[c, t];
  {t, c} = draw[c, 3]; a = Join[a, t];
  Return[{a, b, c}];
]

count = 0;
Do[
 count += Boole[AllTrue[simulate[][[1 ;; 2]], MemberQ[#, z] &]];
 , {1000000}
 ]
count/1000000

(* result: 571612 / 1000000 *)
```

This value 0.571612 is very close to your answer of 561/980 (0.572449).

Comment: +1 thank you!!!